# How to perform dynamic filtering across multiple columns using st.session_state() or on_change()?

Tags: python, pandas, streamlit

I am trying to create a streamlit app where based on 1 filter selection criteria, I want to populate other filter selections. Then, once the submit button is hit, then I want to proceed ahead with processing the data.

```
import streamline as st
import pandas as pd

my_df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Name': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'D'],
    'Color':['red', 'blue', 'blue', 'black', 'black', 'green', 'blue', 
    'yellow', 'white', 'green', 'purple']
})

col1, col2 = st.columns(2)
name_selection = col1.multiselect('select names ', my_df.name.unique().tolist(), key='names')
color_selection = col2.multiselect('select color ', my_df.color.unique().tolist(), key='color')
```

Scenario 1
If I select name as A then the color selection should be only a list of red and blue and not others.

Scenario 2
Similarly, when I choose color as Black first, then I should get only a list of B and C in name list. The filter order is dependent on the user.

In general, I have around 5 to 6 filters and once a user selects a filter condition on any one of the multi select columns, then the other filter conditions should automatically update and populate the list.

How can I achieve this using session_state or on_change() functions?

Do I need a st.form() for this?

Here is scenario 1 -
[image]

and here is scenario 2 -

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First, there is a bit of logic to understand here. Let's say that no selection means no filter, and thus nothing selected is equivalent to everything selected.

At any given point, we expect:

1. the given selections to be associated to a nonempty selection of data
2. any possible, new selection will result in a nonempty selection of data

- If the new selection within a filter is the only selection, this trims the results (and trims available options in other widgets).
- If the new selection within a filter is added to previous selections, this expands the results (and expands the available options in other widgets).
- If a selection is removed from a widget with other selections remaining, this trims the results (and trims available options in other widgets).
- If a selection is removed from a widget with no other selection remaining, this expands the results (and expands the available option in other widgets).

Two filters is a simpler case that might hide the complexity, so consider three filters. Consider:

| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | a |
| B | 2 | a |
| C | 3 | b |
| A | 3 | c |

Suppose that you filter Col3 to [a,b]. Col3 would still have [c] as an unselected option. Col1 would have available selections of [A,B,C] and Col2 would have available selections of [1,2,3]. If you then select [A] for Col1, then options are removed with Col2 now being restricted to [1,3] as options. But then Col3 ends up having [b] removed as an option and thus as a *selection*. This in turn removes [C] as an option from Col1. In fact, if you were trying to select [A,C] for Col1 and [a,b] for Col2, you'd have a problem no matter which way you tried to select it.

The point of the example is, when you don't declare an order to the filters there is a back-and-forth interaction to update the options if you want each filter's options populated based on the selections of other widgets.

---

To simplify the problem consider ordering the filters (or allowing the user to order the filters) to avoid this messiness.

```
import streamlit as st
import pandas as pd

if 'df' not in st.session_state:
    df = pd.DataFrame({
        'Col1':['A','B','C','A'],
        'Col2':[1,2,3,3],
        'Col3':['a','a','b','c']
    })
    st.session_state.df = df

df = st.session_state.df
df_filtered = df.copy()

# Create a value in session state to track where the user is in the process of
# filling out the selections for the filters
if 'confirmed' not in st.session_state:
    st.session_state.confirmed = -2
def confirm(index):
    st.session_state.confirmed = index

st.write('Choose filters in the desired order. Reset filter selection to start over.')
filters = st.multiselect('Choose filters', df.columns, on_change=confirm, args=[-2])
if st.session_state.confirmed == -2:
    st.button('Confirm', on_click=confirm, args=[-1], key='start')

if st.session_state.confirmed >= -1:
    for i, col in enumerate(filters):
        select = st.multiselect(col, df_filtered[col].unique(), key=f'col_{col}', on_change=confirm, args=[i-1])
        if select != []:
            df_filtered = df_filtered[df_filtered[col].isin(select)]
        if i > st.session_state.confirmed:
            st.button('Confirm', on_click=confirm, args=[i])
            break

cols = st.columns(2)
cols[0].write(df)
cols[1].write(df_filtered)
```

[image: Gif of demo code]
Note: I answered a similar question at a later date creating another variation of this sample code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76248797/streamlit-update-options-multiselect).

---

If we want to simply display the filter widgets on the screen and let the user hop around, we have to deal with that interplay. As mentioned, there is an inherent problem with this when selecting "mutually exclusive" rows such as trying to select [A,C] with [a,b] in the example.

In the abstract, I would think of the data in three categories:

1. the rows that are selected by the current filters,
2. the rows that match all but one filter,
3. the rest which don't match two or more filters.

The first category corresponds to your filter selections. The second fills out the unselected options waiting to be selected. Any values that have been removed from possible selection will be in rows in that third category.

You would have to keep in session state for each column/filter: the selected options and the current available options (of which the selected options should be a subset). Given the quirks of this logic though, I'm not sure it's the best one to implement for many filters. If there is a lot of interest, I can try to find time to something out.

Answer (score 0):

I created a component to allow dynamic multiselect filters. See [this demo app](https://dynamic-filters-demo.streamlit.app/) and code below.

```
# install using pip
pip install streamlit-dynamic-filters

from streamlit_dynamic_filters import DynamicFilters

dynamic_filters = DynamicFilters(df, filters=['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4'])
dynamic_filters.display_filters()
dynamic_filters.display_df()
```